# Ubuntu: Reset default routing table

Tags: linux, networking, routes

On my computer I have 2 connections - 3G and LAN.

Before the 3G is connected the routing table would look like this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

After the 3G dialup the routing table would look like this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.64.64.64     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ppp0
10.64.64.64     *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

After the 3G is being disconnected, the routing table would look like this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Since the default routing is disabled after the 3G is being disconnected, there is no way for the system to connect to the server, even the LAN is active.

Is there a way I can modify the routing table after the 3G is being disconnected?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This should be on Super User or Server Fault.

Comment: How does one flag this for Super User/Server Fault these days? Or is it just kept here because 27k people have seen it already? Maybe even AskUbuntu would be a better place for it, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

% sudo route add default gw 192.168.0.1

If the route command is not available, try

% sudo ip route add default via 192.168.0.1

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is is possible that I can use a script which could enable me to do it automatically?